Minitab Graphing - Format Data Point Color
I am using Minitab and have two sets of data for each sample that I would like to show at once on a single plot. I would like the graph to show the individual values of calories in the y-axis as identified by the Operator and Method on the x-axis. I would like to format those data points to show whether they meet the CO2 requirement (<10) by coloring the data points either green or red.



Operator
Method
Calories
CO2




Benny
Op1
92
12


Carroll
Op2
85
7



I have tried different Individual Value Plots and the Graph Builder to make this happen, but I don't see any way for the Calorie data points to reference the CO2 data.
I'm using Minitab 21.4.3.
